# matching single letters in a sentence with a regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match single letters in a sentence. So in ...

```
I want to have my turkey. May I. I 20,000-t bar-b-q
```

I'd like to match

```
*I* want to have my turkey. May *I*. *I* 20,000-t bar-b-q
```

right now I'm using

```
/\b\w\b/
```

as my regular expression, but that is matching

```
*I* want to have my turkey. May *I*. *I* 20,000-*t* bar-*b*-*q*
```

Any suggestions on how to get past that last mile?

Comment: So... how do you define what you want (and do not want) to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to fail if the previous character is a word or a hyphen, or if the next character is a word a or a hyphen:

```
/(?<![\w\-])\w(?![\w\-])/
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/9upmgfG9u4

Note that as mentioned by rtcherry, this will also match single numbers.  To prevent this you may want to change the `\w` that is outside of the character classes to `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 0):

F.J's answer will also include numbers.  This is restricted to ASCII characters, but you really need to define what characters can be side by side an still count as a single letter.

```
/(?<![0-9a-zA-Z\-])[a-zA-Z](?![0-9a-zA-Z\-])/
```

That will also avoid things like `This -> 1a <- is not a single letter.  Neither is -> 2 <- that.`

Answer (score 0):

You are asking far too much of a regular expression. `\w` matches a *word* character, which includes upper and lower case alphabetics, the ten digits, and underscore. So it is the same as `[0-9A-Z_a-z]`.

`\b` matches the (zero-width) boundary where a *word* character doesn't have another *word* character next to it, for instance at the beginning or end of a string, or next to some punctuation or white space.

Using negative look-behinds and look-aheads, this amounts to `\b\w\b` being equivalent to

```
(?<!\w)\w(?!\w)
```

i.e. a *word* character that doesn't have another *word* character before or after it.

As you have found, that finds `t`, `b` and `q` in `20,000-t bar-b-q`. So it's back in your court to define what you *really mean* by *"single letters in a sentence"*.

It nearly works to say "any letter that isn't preceded or followed by a printable character, which is

```
/(?<!\S)[A-Za-z](?!\S)/
```

But that leaves out `I` in `May I.` because it has a dot after it.

So, do you mean a single letter that isn't preceded by a printable character, and is followed by whitespace, a dot, or the end of the string (or a comma, a semicolon or a colon for good measure)? Then you want

```
/(?<!\S)[A-Za-z](?=(?:[\s.,;:]|\z))/
```

which finds exactly three `I` characters in your string.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Except that this also matches single digits and underscores.

Comment: @pguardiario: Very true. I got carried away with the spirit of the `\w`

Comment: There's more things wrong with this, you forgot the `\s` in your expression and I don't think `\z` ever belongs in a `[]`. Also wouldn't `$` be better than `\z`? It was an interesting idea but it seems like a step backwards to me.

Comment: Hmm, `$` matches the end of a line. It's simpler and more appropriate than `\z`. Your `\s` will match before `\n`'s anyway but if it wasn't there the `$` would catch them while `\z` would not.

Comment: @pguardiario:  I disagree: `$` is broken. Try `(0..5).each { |pos| puts /$/.match("xx\n\n", pos).begin(0) }` and then try the same thing with `/\z/`. If that doesn't persuade you then we are going to have to disagree.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating it. `$` and `\z` will match end of line and end of string. Since a single letter at the end of a line _should_ match, `$` is better. Likewise `\z` is better when the match should only be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

As long as we're being picky, non-ASCII letters are easy to include:

```
/(?<![[:alnum:]-])[[:alpha:]](?![[:alnum:]-])/
```

This will avoid matching the `t` in 'Cómo eres tú'

Notice that it's not necessary to escape the `-` when it is the last character in a character class (which I'm not sure that this technically is).

Comment: I'm not sure where we are with POSIX character classes and UTF-8